# init state without constructor in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
  state = { value: 0 };

  increment = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      value: prevState.value + 1
    }));
  };

  decrement = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      value: prevState.value - 1
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.value}
        <button onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.decrement}>-</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Usually what I saw is people do this.state within the constructor function if he used es6 class. If he isn't he probably put the state using getinitialstate function. But above code (yes it's a working code), did not used either both. I have 2 question, what is state here? is that a local variable? if yes why it has no `const`? where does the prevState come from? why arrow function is used in setState? isn't it's easy to just do `this.setState({value:'something'})`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> About the question 2, refer to Dan's great answer here: [Do I need to use setState(function) overload in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43428456/do-i-need-to-use-setstatefunction-overload-in-this-case/43440790#43440790)

---

1. No it's not a local variable. It's the same as declaring `this.state` in constructor.
2. Yes in that case you can just use `this.setState({ value: this.state.value + 1 })`, the result will be the same.

But note that by using functional `setState` you can have some benefits:

1. the setState function can be reused if you declare it outside:

   ```
   const increment = prevState => ({
     value: prevState.value + 1
   })
   ```

   now if you have several components need to use this function, you can just import and reuse the logic everywhere.

   ```
   this.setState(increment)
   ```
2. React squashes several `setState` and executes them in batch. This may cause some unexpected behaviors. Please see the following example:

   http://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/pebLaZ

   ```
   add3 () {
     this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })
     this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })
     this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })
   }
   ```

   executing this function the `count` will only plus 1

   If you use functional setState:

   http://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/dvXmwX

   ```
   const add = state => ({ count: state.count + 1 })
   this.setState(add)
   this.setState(add)
   this.setState(add)
   ```

   count will +3 as you expected.

You can see the docs here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: *"Yes in that case you can just use `this.setState({ value: this.state.value + 1 })`, the result will be the same."* is simply incorrect, as the documentation I pointed to in my answr (and you at the end of yours) quite clearly says. To say "you can just use [it]" is flatly wrong.

Comment: I mean the `increment` function of OP's code, there is only 1 setState statement, then it's fine

Comment: No, it isn't. From the documentation: *"**React** may batch multiple `setState()` calls into a single update for performance..."* (my emphasis). So if there are multiple calls to `increment` that React thinks it can batch (even if it isn't obvious from the code that it can), it will; and the result will be wrong. If it were just you intentionally calling `setState` repeatedly, you'd be able to handle it yourself.

Comment: React only batches setState when you call setState several times in a single handler, so it is safe if your function contains only 1 setState

Comment: See the end of my answer for proof that that isn't true. The batching can happen in non-obvious ways; writing code relying on `this.state` in a mutator is simply poor practice. Again, the React devs created the function version of `setState` *for a reason*.

Comment: Yes I understand it, my comments above are not accuracy enough. It should be *calling setState several times in a tick*. But I think if one really understands his code then a normal setState is safe enough.

Comment: Well, I tried. :-) It isn't "safe enough." It's a bad assumption which will eventually bite you, which is why the React documentation is quite clear about not doing that.

Comment: I use setState with object a lot, for almost all the scenarios there is no issue at all if keeping the code clean. And for some other cases just need to pass a callback to setState, thus I never run into any issue that caused by setState's behavior

Comment: Anecdotes are not evidence. Just because it hasn't bitten you, that doesn't mean it won't, or that it hasn't bitten other people.

Comment: Yup that's why I said must understand your code well

Comment: Just like what you said, React provides the simple object style setState for some reason, you can always feel free use it if you understand its behavior. btw thanks for pointing out all these things and discussions, your example is a great one. In fact I'm trying to use the functional style more, it does have some benefits (for me mostly is to make the code clean and separate the logics).

Comment: *"React provides the simple object style setState for some reason"* Yes: For those cases (and there are a lot of them!) where you're *not* using `this.state` when determining the state to use. :-)

Answer (score 24):

> I have 2 question, what is `state` here?

An instance property, like setting `this.state = {value: 0};` in a constructor. It's using the [Public Class Fields proposal](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-public-fields/) currently at Stage 2. (So are `increment` and `decrement`, which are instance fields whose values are arrow functions so they close over `this`.)

> is that a local variable?

No.

> where does the prevState come from? why arrow function is used in setState? isn't it's easy to just do this.setState({value:'something'})?

From [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous):

> React may batch multiple `setState()` calls into a single update for performance.
>
> Because `this.props` and `this.state` may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.
>
> For example, this code may fail to update the counter:
>
> ```
> // Wrong
> this.setState({
>   counter: this.state.counter + this.props.increment,
> });
> ```
>
> To fix it, use a second form of `setState()` that accepts a function rather than an object. That function will receive the previous state as the first argument, and the props at the time the update is applied as the second argument:
>
> ```
> // Correct
> this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
>   counter: prevState.counter + props.increment
> }));
> ```

...which is exactly what the quoted code is doing. This would be wrong:

```
// Wrong
increment = () => {
  this.setState({
    value: this.state.value + 1
  });
};
```

...because it's relying on the state of `this.state`, which the above tells us not to; so the quoted code does this instead:

```
increment = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    value: prevState.value + 1
  }));
};
```

---

Here's proof that React may batch calls in a non-obvious way and why we need to use the callback version of `setState`: Here, we have `increment` and `decrement` being called *twice* per click rather than once (once by the button, once by a span containing the button). Clicking `+` *once* should increase the counter to 2, because `increment` is called twice. But because we haven't used the function callback version of `setState`, it doesn't: One of those calls to `increment` becomes a no-op because we're using a stale `this.state.value` value:

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {
  state = { value: 0 };

  increment = () => {
    /*
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      value: prevState.value + 1
    }));
    */
    console.log("increment called, this.state.value = " + this.state.value);
    this.setState({
      value: this.state.value + 1
    });
  };
  
  fooup = () => {
    this.increment();
  };

  decrement = () => {
    /*
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      value: prevState.value - 1
    }));
    */
    console.log("decrement called, this.state.value = " + this.state.value);
    this.setState({
      value: this.state.value - 1
    });
  };
  
  foodown = () => {
    this.decrement();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.value}
        <span onClick={this.fooup}>
          <button onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
        </span>
        <span onClick={this.foodown}>
          <button onClick={this.decrement}>-</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Counter />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

With the function callback, it works correctly (no calls to `increment` become no-ops):

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {
  state = { value: 0 };

  increment = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      console.log("Incrementing, prevState.value = " + prevState.value);
      return {
        value: prevState.value + 1
      };
    });
  };
  
  fooup = () => {
    this.increment();
  };

  decrement = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      console.log("Decrementing, prevState.value = " + prevState.value);
      return {
        value: prevState.value - 1
      };
    });
  };
  
  foodown = () => {
    this.decrement();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.value}
        <span onClick={this.fooup}>
          <button onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
        </span>
        <span onClick={this.foodown}>
          <button onClick={this.decrement}>-</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Counter />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

In this case, of course, we can look at the `render` method and say "Hey, `increment` will get called twice during a click, I'd better use the callback version of `setState`." But rather than assuming it's safe to use `this.state` when determining next state, best practice is *not* to assume that. In a complex component, it's easy to use mutator methods in a way that the author of the mutator method may not have thought of. Hence the statement by the React authors:

> Because `this.props` and `this.state` may be updated asynchronously, **you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state**.

Comment: I used lots of this `this.setState({
    value: this.state.value + 1
  });` it worked at least, nothing wrong with that. I haven't experience any issue doing that.

Comment: @JennyMok: "nothing wrong with that" -- yes, there is. Just because it hasn't bitten you yet, that doesn't mean there isn't anything wrong with it. See the documentation. The React devs probably know React better than we do, and didn't just add this form accepting a function on a whim.

Answer (score 3):

**Answer to Question 1:**

Yes, you can initialize state without a constructor for a React class component:

```
class Counter extends Component {
  state = { value: 0 };

  handleIncrement = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      value: prevState.value + 1
    }));
  };

  handleDecrement = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      value: prevState.value - 1
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.value}

        <button onClick={this.handleIncrement}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleDecrement}>-</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

It uses **class field declarations**. You can checkout the sample application over [here](https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/react-alternative-class-component-syntax). You can also use state in React function components (without a constructor), but using higher-order components or render prop components. You can find out more about it [here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-without-constructor/).

**Answer to Question 2:** There are two ways to update local state in React with `this.setState`. You can either use an object or a function. The object is just fine if you are not relying on props or state of the component to update its state.  If you rely on props or state, you should use the function instead, because it always has the most recent props and state at the time of execution. All this is because `this.setState()` is executed asynchronous, so you could use stale state or props when updating your local state with the object instead of the function. You can read more about it [here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/learn-react-before-using-redux/).

Comment: for the way you init state just in the local space of the Component {...right here...} can u get a ref to props to initialize the state value with like `this.props.value` rather than `state = { value: 0 }` i.e. without a constructor i want like you have but: state = { value: this.props.value } - probably not possible eh?