# How to handle asynchronous calls to setState in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a method that toggles a boolean value in state by copying the value then updating state:

```
toggleSelected = () => {
    let selected = this.state.lists.selected;
    selected = !selected;
    this.setState({
      // update state
    });
};
```

I have another method, fired by an onClick handler, that calls `toggleSelected` twice:

```
switchList = (listName) => {
    const currList = this.getCurrentList();
    if(listName === currList.name) return;
    this.toggleSelected(listName);
    this.toggleSelected(currList);
};
```

However it appears that the state doesn't finish getting set from the first call by the time the second call runs; if I set a timeout on the second call, it works fine.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Why is it being called twice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43428456/do-i-need-to-use-setstatefunction-overload-in-this-case/43440790#43440790

Comment: In short setState calls are batched together

Comment: @VivekN calling it twice to toggle the value at two different parts in state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to what @SLaks suggested, useful sometimes, is using the `setState(new_state, callback)` method. The callback will be run once the state is updated and "visible".

In general, `setState` will not change the state immediately so that it is visible in `this.state`. From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall.

Comment: Is this preferable to using a lifecycle hook?

Comment: Depends on how you structure the code. In general, I try to set a single `setState` per UI action explicitly because of this. If it's not possible, I'll do the callback, because it makes the code a little bit more readable.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [React State/Lifecycle docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), the correct way to update state based on previous state is by passing a function into the `setState()` call, eg:

```
toggleSelected() {
  this.setState((prevState, props) => {
    return {
      lists: {
        selected : ! prevState.lists.selected
      }
    };
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is why you should always [pass a lambda to `setState()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate), so that it will give you the actual current state:

```
this.setState(state => ({ ..., selected: !state.lists.selected }))
```

Comment: How will this solve the issue. setState calls are batched, so even this won't work

Comment: @SLaks, do you mean `{...!state.lists.selected}`? If so, this wouldn't work since in my case `state.lists.selected` is a boolean not an object.

Comment: @AndrewJensen: No; I meant `selected:`.