# Javascript async-mutex does not seem to lock properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mutex, race-condition, uppy

I am using [`async-mutex`](https://github.com/DirtyHairy/async-mutex because there is a race condition in my code from concurrent requests returning. And upon all of the concurrent requests resolving, they each need to add something from the response into a state array.

I have included a codesandbox replicating this issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-haze-2407uy

I will also post the code here for reference:

```js
import Uppy from "@uppy/core";
import XHRUpload from "@uppy/xhr-upload";
import { DragDrop, ProgressBar } from "@uppy/react";
import { Mutex } from "async-mutex";

import { useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [stuff, setStuff] = useState([]);
  const uppy = new Uppy({
    meta: { type: "file" },
    autoProceed: true
  });
  uppy.use(XHRUpload, {
    endpoint: `google.com/upload`
  });

  const mutex = new Mutex();

  uppy.on("upload-error", (_, response) => {
    mutex.acquire().then((release) => {
      let joined = stuff.concat("test");
      setStuff(joined);
      console.log(stuff);
      release();
    });
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DragDrop
        uppy={uppy}
        locale={{
          strings: {
            // Text to show on the droppable area.
            // `%{browse}` is replaced with a link that opens the system file selection dialog.
            dropHereOr: "Drop here or %{browse}",
            // Used as the label for the link that opens the system file selection dialog.
            browse: "browse"
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I expect, when uploading two files (the upload server is bogus but that is intended, because all requests (one per file) will trigger the `upload-error` event) that the `stuff` array will end up like `['test', 'test']`. However, that does not happen:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is because the "state" (no pun intended) of the `stuff` state is uncertain at the time of running `setState`, due to the nature of `setStuff` and state setters in general being asynchronous.

The solution is to

a) use `await` because in any case the mutex lock acquisition is a promise

b) pass a lambda function into `setStuff` that guarantees the state of `stuff` will be up to date, as opposed to just assuming `stuff` will be up to date (which it won't be)

```js
    uppy.on('upload-error',  async (_, response) => {
        await mutex.acquire().then((release) => {
            setStuff((prevState => {
                return prevState.concat('test');
            }));
            release();
        });
    })
```

For more information, check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/44726537/8652920