# Why does a react component maintain a state if it's a class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I see react components have "this.state" but why does it have that if I could just have various "this.var1", "this.var2", ie class variables. If it's defined as a **class** in es6, then it already has its own state.

I see that if I change the state with "setState" then it rerenders. but wouldn't it be easier to just set class variables and then call this.rerender() whenever I see fit? Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons why `react` uses `state` instead of class methods to decide whether to render the component.

You can have class variables along with `state`. `setState` is async which allows react to optimize renders. The render method called after `setState` happens implicitly so we don't need to do it every time.

There are bunch of blogs and tweets on this topic.

[Do I need to use setState(function) overload in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43428456/do-i-need-to-use-setstatefunction-overload-in-this-case/43440790#43440790)

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/824309659775467527?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

Have a good read through [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) in the React documentation. React has several optimizations around, and features related to, state, such as asynchronous and consolidated state updates. Calling `setState` begins a non-trivial process which can't be trivially replaced with object properties and calls to [`forceUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate).

One of the links in the `setState` page linked above is *In depth: Why isn’t this.state updated immediately?*, which links to [this github issue comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527#issuecomment-360199710) which is too long to replicate here, but hits the main points "Guaranteeing Internal Consistency" and "Enabling Concurrent Updates".