# Typescript in React: State will not be placed in the constructor will cause an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

[image]
as shown,  State will not be placed in the constructor will cause an error.
But, if the state is placed inside the constructor, it won't.

However, If you declare a type for state， it is also fine.

[image]

please

Comment: please refer this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993989/init-state-without-constructor-in-react

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
state = {
 quota: null
}
```

It *replaces* the inherited `state` type definition. The correct way to do it is to add an annotation

```
state: IState = {
 quota: null
}
```

Which is what you already have figured out.

When you do it in the constructor you are not *redefining* just assigning, and hence the inherited `IState` type gets used automatically.

Comment: thank you for you answer. and i still have a question.
why is the type of replaced state is `never` not  `any`?