# Proper way of defining/initializing state in reactjs or react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So far I understand there are two ways to define state in react class.

The first as many people use them, is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

export default class Test extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = {
       text: 'hello'
     }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.text}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The second one is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

export default class Test extends Component {

  state = {
     text: "hello"
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.text}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The difference is at using constructor or not. What is the effect and is there any difference at all between the two? If there is, which one should I use?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [init state without constructor in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993989/init-state-without-constructor-in-react)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it better to define state in constructor or using property initializers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37788342/is-it-better-to-define-state-in-constructor-or-using-property-initializers)

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the reference!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both methods are fine. Second one is the short-hand method

Answer (score 1):

Both methods are correct. Make sure you have support for class properties enabled in the babelrc. If you are using CRA both will work. Constructor one is better on the eyes if you want to seed the initial state from props.