# React cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

**Updated code**
Initialized constructor and placed filter and loadOptions in class render method.
Still showing error saying that this.state.cars.filter is not a function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';


export default class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputValue: null,
      cars: []
    };
  }

 componentDidMount() {
  fetch(url)
  .then(res => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({...prevState, cars: res}))
})
}
  handleInputChange = (newValue) => {
    const inputValue = newValue.replace(/\W/g, '');
    this.setState({ inputValue });
    return inputValue;
  };
  render() {
    const filterCars = (inputValue) => {
      return this.state.cars.filter((i) =>
        i.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
      );
    };
    const loadOptions = (
      inputValue,
      callback) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        callback(filterCars(inputValue));
      }, 1000);
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <AsyncSelect
          cacheOptions
          loadOptions={loadOptions}
          defaultOptions
          onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Example code of json file that Im fetching data from

```
[{"make":"KIA","link":"\/images\/image.jpg"},{"make":"BMW","link":"\/images\/image.jpg"}]
```

Comment: You should be defining your functions inside `Search` as methods, also you are missing `Search`'s `constructor` function where you need to initialize the `state`.

Comment: I thought you could initialize the state without using constructor.. At least they said that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52826907/17771314 Or am I missing something?

Comment: Technically you can, but it's not recommended since you wouldn't be able to to use `props` for initialization for example. If you are using class components I think it's a better practice to include `constructor` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here. First is that you should declare state inside of a constructor, so instead of declaring state like that, do the following:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {inputValue: '', cars: []}
}
```

Then you need to deal with your `state mutations`. Whenever you call `setState`, you are essentially giving it a new `object` which it sets the `state` to. You do not reassign the `properties`, you return a new `object`.

To resolve this reassignment issue, `ES6` has introduced the `spread operator` which was not specifically designed to deal with mutations but it helps a lot.

Essentially, whenever you want to create a copy of an object, you don't do

```
let a = b
```

instead you do

```
let a = {...b}
```

With this change, changes on A will not reflect on B. So you make a copy instead of a duplicate.

How you can use this to avoid state mutation?

Whenever you call `setState`, make sure to first spread the rest of the state accross the new one before making any property changes:

```
setState(prevState => ({...prevState, cars: res}))
```

This way, you do not essentially remove the `inputValue` from your state object which can cause undefined issues.

Back to the main issue, your function `filterCars` is located outside of your class and in there you are trying to access `this.state`. Move the `filterCars` function inside of the class and your error will be resolved but if you don't resolve the mutation issues, it will not work as expected.

Comment: I updated my code as you said. Still getting error when filtering.

Comment: Does it still occur when reading "state" or when reading "cars" or "inputValue"?

Comment: So I got error saying this.state.cars.filter is not a function. I presume its when reading cars.

Comment: That means that `this.state.cars` is not an `iterable object`. Try to do `console.log` on `this.state.cars` and see if it returns an array or `undefined`.

Comment: Also try to do `this.state.cars?.filter` instead as that could solve your issue but that is not really a solution, just a temporary fix which could result in runtime errors down the line.